# Session PHP expire almost immediately

Tags: php, session

I've got a problem with my Session in PHP, if I refresh my page it set a new session_id each time.
I use the PHP built in server and PHP 7.1 and nothing more than that :

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo session_id();
```

Each refresh give me a new Session Id. Each ? Not really in fact, if I refresh super quickly I have the same session id for 1 or 2 seconds.

I don't know where to look, my php.ini seems correct, my code too I believe.
My folder to register session is 777.

Where could I look or what test could I do ?

Edit : I don't know why but changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the built in server solved the issue

Comment: Make sure error reporting is on and reporting notices. Then check to see if you have output before you call session_start()

Comment: I just found how to bypass the error, (error reporting was on and no output before) Im' updating my post !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the built in server solved the issue.